# How to use yarn to run a self-contained Spark app remotely

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am creating a self-contained Scala program that uses Spark for parallelization in some parts. In my specific situation, the Spark cluster is available through yarn.

I need my Spark job to load a hdfs file located on a hadoop cluster not accessible directly through my local machine. So, I create SOCKS proxy through ssh tunnel by including these properties in hdfs-site.xml.

```
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.socks.server</name>
    <value>localhost:7070</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.rpc.socket.factory.class.default</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.net.SocksSocketFactory</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.client.use.legacy.blockreader</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
```

where 7070 is the dynamic port to the hadoop gateway machine.

```
ssh -fCND 7070 <hadoop-gateway-machine>
```

This allows me to access hdfs files locally, when I am using Spark in `local[*]` master configuration for testing.

However, when I run a real Spark job on yarn deployed on the same hadoop cluster (configured by `yarn-site.xml`, `hdfs-site.xml`, and `core-site.xml` in the classpath), I see errors like:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Library directory '<project-path>/assembly/target/scala-2.11/jars' does not exist; make sure Spark is built.
```

So, I set `spark.yarn.jars` property directly on sparkConf. This at least starts a yarn application. When I go the application url I just keep seeing this message in one of the worker logs:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher
```

And this message in one more hadoop worker log (apparently the Spark worker that could not connect to driver)

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to connect to driver!
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.waitForSparkDriver(ApplicationMaster.scala:484)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runExecutorLauncher(ApplicationMaster.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$main$1.apply$mcV$sp(ApplicationMaster.scala:653)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:68)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1693)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:651)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:674)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
```

My question is, what is the right way of running self-contained Spark apps on a yarn cluster. How do you do it so you don't have to specify `spark.yarn.jars` and other properties? Should you include spark-defaults.conf in the classpath as well?